# Where does this proof of Caratheodory's theorem break down for using n vectors, instead of n+1?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-hulls

In the referenced text below, (1) is referring to Caratheodory's theorem for conical combinations.

For Caratheodory's theorem for convex combinations, I'm trying to understand what the purpose is of the up-projection. Now intuitively and from counterexamples I know that just n vectors doesn't suffice for convex combinations. However, it seems to me that if we just don't do the up-projection and go through the proof, we can still invoke (1) and go through the proof as normal...? (I'm sure I am mistaken, but not sure why.)

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: Theorem statement]

[image: Caratheodory's theorem for convex hulls]

Comment: The up-projection is there to ensure that these $\alpha_i$'s sum up to one.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. I thought the $\alpha_i$ add up to 1 by assumption of $x \in conv(X)$?

Comment: That is true. But to make the argument work, this condition has to be encoded in $cone(Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that if you take $X$ to be the vertices of a full-dimensional simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $|X|=n+1$ and the vector which is their average cannot be represented as a convex combination of less than $n+1$ vectors taken from $X$.